# Have any US Presidents committed indictable offenses?

Tags: united-states, president

Recently there have been rumors that the Manhattan DA is going to indict Donald Trump for campaign finance violations over paying hush money to Stormy Daniels. The word "unprecedented" is often used to describe this potential arrest of a former President.

But is it the indictment that's unprecedented, or the fact that the former President committed such a serious offense in the first place?

The only one in my lifetime I can think of is Nixon, but Ford preemptively pardoned him so he couldn't be indicted.

EDIT (after Raveesh's answer, because I realized I wasn't clear):

To keep this tractable, let's limit it to US laws. International law opens up a large can of worms due to opinions about whether military actions constitute war crimes.

Comment: I assume you're referring solely to indictable offences under US law, and that "indictable offences under the Nuremberg principles" (as discussed in Raveesh's answer) don't count if they are (or were at the time) considered legal under US law?

Comment: I've edited the question to restrict it to US laws.

Comment: Are you primarily asking about crimes that are grounds for a US domestic indictment?  I know we are all abuzz about the ICC these days, but, really, answers and comments bringing Chomsky to a Stormy Daniels issue seems to be missing the point by several country miles.  Can you clarify that in the Q?

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Yes, that's why I added the last paragraph to my question. I'm looking for things comparable to the likely indictment of Trump.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Unfortunately the end note about *Lets limit this to US law* was added **after my answer**.  As I pointed out to OP this violates [SE principles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286803/change-to-question-invalidates-my-answer-what-to-do/286804#286804).  So I hope he will restore it to the original form. A US president [has never been indited](https://www.washingtonpost.com/history/2023/03/21/president-arrested-ulysses-grant-speeding/) is just a google away

Comment: could you also clarify that we are talking about a criminal indictment, not a POTUS-removal indictment.  I know, should be obvious, but...

Comment: What is a "POTUS-removal indictment"? Do you mean impeachment?

Comment: @Raveesh I think that guideline is too strict. I'm not changing my question, just clarifying it because your answer indicated that it was too broad.

Comment: @Barmar yes, i meant impeachment here.  but impeachment (House-side) is the *indictment* part of the procedure.  Just probably best to keep the Clinton, Trump, Nixon, etc... impeachment considerations out of it.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Impeachment isn't a legal issue. Several other Presidents have been impeached, so obviously that's not "unprecedented" (although 2 impeachments of Trump was a new record).

Comment: Meh, "indictable" might still be opinion-based. Probably simpler to ask if any were indicted on criminal charges.

Comment: @Fizz I'm pretty sure none were ever indicted. So the question is whether there were Presidents who could have been indicted, but prosecutors chose to give them a pass. Assuming Trump is indicted, he might have a legitimate claim that he's being singled out for political reasons.

Comment: That's why Nixon also doesn't count -- his pardon protected him.

Comment: Okay, so to make this answerable by something other than speculation/opinion on who could have been indicted but wasn't, I suppose the only real criterion is that some DA said they considered it?

Comment: @Fizz Maybe I should have asked in [history.se]. I'm assuming that the activities of most Presidents are documented well enough that it would be obvious. It would be hard for one of them to rob a bank without it being well known.

Comment: A nitpick in the realm of language precision: Trump wasn't yet president when the Stormy Daniels payments were made, much less former president.  If evidence arose that George W Bush had committed bribery in his business career in the 1970s, would that count?  Would the treason committed by the first few presidents against the king of Great Britain count?

Comment: @phoog I think the Bush example would count -- what's "unprecedented" that the investigation and potential prosecution is against a former President. The founding fathers example seems a little silly -- the entire revolution was clearly an offense against Britain.

Answer (score 3):

We know that at least two recent presidents committed felonies.

We have Richard Nixon, who Obstructed Justice as he tried to thwart the investigation into the Watergate burglaries. Nixon was also an Accessory After the Fact to those Burglaries, and he could also have been charged with Conspiracy as he was paying the burglars to be quiet. There are a whole slew of other crimes related to Watergate but those are the highlights for which Nixon could have been indicted

- When all of these facts came to light, Nixon resigned from the presidency, and was pardoned a month later (likely part of the agreement for him to go quietly).

We also have Bill Clinton, who in 1998 committed Grand Jury Perjury and Obstructed Justice when he lied about an affair in a sworn affidavit. Clinton was impeached for this lie, but Clinton was acquitted by the Senate.

- Subsequent to the acquittal, Clinton was cited for Contempt of Court and fined $90,000. Clinton was also investigated by the Arkansas bar and in a plea deal had his law license suspended for 5 years. Clinton also agreed to another plea deal with the special counsel Robert Ray paying a $25,000 fine to avoid indictments.
- Clinton could have quite easily been indicted once he left office had he not agreed to those plea deals. While opinions differ on whether Clinton got off easy or not for lying in a sworn affidavit about sex, a 5 year law license suspension is pretty hefty. Just consider, Jimmy McGill broke into his brother's house, destroyed evidence, and assaulted his brother, and Mr. Better Call Saul lost his license for just 1 year!

--

There are plenty of conspiracy theories, some of which I believe, about Ronald Reagan and George W Bush committing felonies, but there is no hard evidence about either. George HW Bush and Jimmy Carter kept their noses pretty clean, while Barack Obama avoided scandal like the plague during his stay in the White House.

Comment: The question already mentions Nixon and his pardon, but Clinton is a good answer.

Comment: @F1Krazy you are correct, Nixon was mentioned. I guess that I got too excited about having an answer, lol.

Comment: **5 year law license suspension is pretty hefty** -- is it much of a punishment if you don't plan on acting as a lawyer? It seems like mainly a symbolic act, perhaps with a little impact on reputation, but he doesn't seem to have suffered much.

Comment: Would Reagan's conspiracy theories likely be related to Iran Contra?

Comment: @barmar I had hoped that by comparing Clinton's suspension to the one received by Jimmy "Better Call Saul" McGill, that I'd be injecting a bit of levity into whether a 5 year suspension was excessive, or light.  A 5 year suspension is stiff, the lawyer who altered e-mail evidence in the Carter Page case got a 1 year suspension, for comparison. While Clinton obviously did fine without the license, he surely could have used it during the 5 years, so there was a penalty.

Comment: I got the joke, but the obvious difference is that Jimmy wanted to be a lawyer, while Clinton had long ended his legal career. It's kind of like being sentenced to house arrest when you live in a lavish mansion.

Comment: @Barmar Iran Contra is one possibility. Did Reagan know? If he did that was a felony.  Another is the Iran Embassy Hostages who were released an hour after Reagan was inaugurated. Carter tried hard to negotiate a release before the election but Iran chose to wait till Reagan was in office. Then Reagan covertly sells arms to Iran in spite of the 2 countries being enemies. There are a few conspiracy theories out there claiming that Regan's 1980 election campaign cut a deal with Iran to stymie Carter's efforts. If true, that's treason.

Comment: I hadn't heard about that "deal", but I was still a teenager at the time and didn't follow politics very closely.

Comment: @barmar The Iran hostages looks very dirty. After being held for 444 days the Iranians release them an hour after Reagan's inauguration!?! Then Reagan secretly sells arms to Iran, a sworn enemy?!?  Looks dirty, but there are benign explanations.

Comment: @barmar About Clinton's license suspension, that punishment was for him as a lawyer, committing perjury. The punishment was focused on him being a lawyer. I suppose for the regular law, Clinton got impeached, and then paid two fines.

Comment: The punishment makes sense in context (you did something a lawyer shouldn't do, so you can't be a lawyer), but it seems like it was mainly just a slap on the wrist at the time.

Comment: @Barmar This is a productive conversation, you have helped me sharpen my thoughts on this issue. I think that we agree the 5 year suspension was both an appropriate and a severe punishment for a lawyer. The slap on the wrist part were the other punishments: $90K fine for contempt of court and $25K plea deal for the perjury.  $115K in 2000 is a lot of money, and the Clinton's were broke. But he avoided an indictment. Is that leniency? Or fairness? For perjury about an affair.